# unique field validations in model based on foriegn key yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table called `menusoffered` where I am storing `menuname` based on `restaurantid` which is a foreign key.

In my `menusoffered` model I have declared that `menuname` has a unique validator, but this is checking the uniqueness from the entire table.

I want it to check uniqueness based on `restaurantid`,
Can any one help me how to make this `menuname` unique for particular `restaurantid`?

**Below is my given menu model,**

```
class Menusoffered extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'menusoffered';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
            ['phase_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Please select Phase'],
            ['menuname', 'required'],           
            ['price', 'required'],
            [['price'],'integer' , 'message' =>'Price should be in digits'],
            [['image_url'], 'file'],
            [['description', 'status'], 'string'],
            [['createdts','restaurantid'], 'safe'],
            ['master_menu_sepcality_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Please select Speciality'],
            ['master_menu_type_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Please select Type'],
            ['menuname', 'unique', 'with'=>'restaurantid'],
            [['restaurantid'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Restaurant::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['restaurantid' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'master_menu_sepcality_id' => 'Master Menu Sepcality ID',
        'master_menu_type_id' => 'Master Menu Type ID',
        'item' => 'Item',
        'price' => 'Price',
        'restaurantid' => 'Restaurantid',
        'phase_id' => 'Phase ID',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'image_url' => 'Image Url',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'createdts' => 'Createdts',
    ];
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [Yii2 Unique Validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html):

```
// a1 and a2 need to be unique together, only a1 will receive error message
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
```

Comment: thanks friend it worked for me only thing as there was no restaurantid field in my active form so i added hidden field there it worked thank u very much